# Javac -Xlint:deprecation log

Tags: java, java-7, javac

```
import java.util.Date;
Public class Sample
{
    Public static void main(String... arg)
    {   
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.getMinutes());
    }
}
```

In java6, if I use `javac -Xlint:deprecation Sample.java`, I can get the following deprecated log.

```
Ex: [deprecation] getMinutes() in java.util.Date has been deprecated.
```

Here, the deprecated method, classname and package name are clearly explained.
When I execute the same command in java 7, I could get only the deprecated classname and method name not package name.

```
Ex: [deprecation] getMinutes() in Date has been deprecated.
```

Can anyone explain why these changes introduced in Java 7? Also is there any possible to make java 7 to give the same deprecated log as java 6?